# Find multiple fragments of string in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string of IDs in CSV format in an input box

`12,23,26,32`

I have to check if this string contains 23 or 24, if yes then return false, else return true

Comment: All the answers to this point are quite limited, assuming that you'll only ever need to check for 23 or 24. If you need it, you might get a more reusable/flexible answer if you rephrase the question :)

Comment: Note that Internet Explorer < 9 does not support `indexOf` on arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexOf. You can check if it contains a subString. If not found, it returns -1

```
var str = "12,23,26,32"
return !(str.indexOf("23")!=-1 || str.indexOf("24")!=-1) // Dont have 23 or 24
```

=======EDIT=======

Like @Matt said in comment, this solution will work also to "12,239,26,32" and thats not the point.

Make the split before check the indexOf, then you will get the element between the commas.

```
var array = "12,23,26,32".split(",");
return !(array.indexOf("23")!=-1 || array.indexOf("24")!=-1) // Dont have 23 or 24
```

Comment: The trouble is, that will match if the input string is "12,239,26,32". I think the OP wanted each csv of the input string to be an atomic unit to test against.

Comment: I see... You have a point. A solution is make a split before checking, right? I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
!/(^|,)2[34](,|$)/.test( str );
```

or if there may be whitespace present

```
!/(^|,)\s*2[34]\s*(,|$)/.test( str );
```

The RegExp `test` method returns `true` if the string argument matches the regular expression or `false` if it doesn't. The `!` inverts the result of the test call.

`^` is the metacharacter for the start of the string, so`(^|,)` means either 'at the start of the string' or 'one comma character'.

It can't be written `[^,]` as that would mean 'one character that isn't a comma', and it can't be written `[,^]` as that means 'one character that is either a comma or a literal `^` character.

`2[34]` means 2 followed by 3 or 4.
`(,|$)` means a comma or the end `$` of the string.
`\s*` means zero or more space characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/(?:^|,)(23|24)(?:,|$)/.test("12,23,26,32")) {
   /* found 23 or 24 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = "12,23,26,32";

var isFound = (str.indexOf('23') || str.indexOf('24')) > -1;
```

Comment: The trouble is, that will match if the input string is "12,239,26,32". I think the OP wanted each csv of the input string to be an atomic unit to test against.

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "12,23,26,32";

var obj = str.split(",");

var isFound = false;

for(i=0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
     if(obj[i] == "23" || obj[i] == "24")
     {
          isFound = true;
          break;
     }
}
return isFound;
```

Comment: -1, should always specify the radix on parseInt. Also, why convert to a number and then compare it?

Comment: +1, it's closer to what the OP probably wants than any of the indexOf or regex answers.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, Can you explain this? `should always specify the radix on the string`

Comment: parseInt() takes two parameters, the string to parse and the "base" (technically called the radix) of the number system to parse to (10 for decimal, 8 for octal, etc.). If not specified, javascript will assume based on the string format, and thus `parseInt('032')` will likely be assumed to be octal.

Comment: @Matt Sach. No, its not closer at all: _"if yes then return false, else return true"_

Comment: @MikeM once if it is true the condition gets breaked, why does it need check if condition mets?

Comment: @MattSach, But what's wrong in comparing after converting to number? that work right ?

Comment: @DON: I don't think there's anything wrong with comparing after converting to a number, unless the it's possible for the input not to be numerical. I think Evan was just saying that the `parseInt()` is unnecessary, as opposed to actually wrong.